# selenium webdriver facebook logout C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to Selenium Webdriver, I tried to logout from facebook using below code but not able to logout. The Exception I am getting is **NoSuchElementException** as code is not able to send click command on drop down arrow.

I tried **wait time** as well as using by using **By.ID** but still face the same issue.

Any idea how I can fix this.?

Thank You[The logout button screen capture for facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWu0c.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace TestFrameWork.TC
{
    class LogIn
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = "https://www.facebook.com/";

            //Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account'(My Account)
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).Click();

            // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'log' (Username)
            // Enter Username on the element found by above desc.
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("your email");

            // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)
            // Enter Password on the element found by the above desc.
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys("Your Pass");

            //Submit the Form
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_2")).Click();

            //Finding the Logout button
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='userNavigationLabel']")).Click();

            //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            //Click on Logout Button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_17_3")).Click();

            // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account_logout' (Log Out)
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).Click();

            //Close Driver
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its the problem with your locator , because i didn't find any match for your logout locator on inspecting the logout button.

You can set the chrome options to disable the location notification like this:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/GitProject/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I am able to click on the logout with the below code and i hope this help you.

```
//to click on the logout menu
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='logoutMenu']")).Click();

//to click on the logout 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='uiScrollableAreaContent']//li//*[text()='Log Out']")).Click();
```

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: The first part to open drop down menu worked fine. I am still not able to logout by using what you suggested. I tried other ways as well but still no luck. Will have to search for another way to make it work.

The above code would not even reach the drop down while working with chrome, instead it will send a pop-up for location access which will disturb the code. I will disable all the setting in chrome and than rerun it.

Thank You for your help though.

Comment: Give some sleep before clicking logout and try

Comment: First you should something to close the pop-up , i have verified my code by closing the pop-up manually and i am successfully able to logout from facebook.

Comment: I have updated my code and its working for me , have a look at it.